# How to find the coordinates for a worldline with $y=z=0$ that experiences constant acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I'm studying some lecture notes on special relativity and at some point one considers an inertial system in which a particle has $4$-velocity and $4$-acceleration given by

$$U = (c\frac{dt}{ds}, \frac{dx}{ds}, 0, 0), \quad A = (c\frac{d^2t}{ds^2}, \frac{d^2x}{ds^2}, 0, 0) \, .$$

We also know the acceleration is constant with magnitude $\kappa$.
I understand these $4$-vectors have to satisfy the equations
$$c^2(dt/ds)^2 - (dx/ds)^2 = c^2 , \quad c^2(d^2t/ds^2)^2 - (d^2x/ds^2)^2 = - \kappa^2,$$
though I don't understand why there is a minus sign in front of $\kappa$ (does one implicitly assume the acceleration is opposite to the x-direction?).
However, I have no clue how to deduce the following pair of equations which seem to come out of the blue, namely
$$c\frac{d^2t}{ds^2} = \kappa \sqrt{(dt/ds)^2 - 1} , \quad \frac{d^2x}{ds^2} = \kappa \frac{dt}{ds}.$$
Any hint?

Comment: What is your source? Can you check your equations for typos?

Comment: @robphy I checked my lecture notes and there is no typos in my post. So, If there is a typo then it's in the lecture notes themselves.

Comment: (I see that an edit was done... so the units are more consistent now.)

Comment: I meant no typos in the last two equations. I fixed a forgotten square in one equation.

Answer (score 1):

The 4-velocity is timelike.
The 4-acceleration is spacelike.
So their square-norms have opposite signs.
(These 4-vectors are actually orthogonal to each other.
Since the square-norm of the 4-velocity is a constant, taking its derivative with respect to proper time reveals this orthogonality condition.)

Comment: I understand that g(U,U) = c^2 > 0 and g(A, U) = 0, but now how do you deduce g(A,A) < 0, ie. that the 4-acceleration is spacelike?

Comment: What happens when you symbolically compute $d/ds( g(U,U) )$? Can you write this in terms of U and A? Then use what you know about $g(U,U)$. (Hint: An analogue would be the relationship between the acceleration vector and the velocity vector for uniform circular motion.)

Comment: d/ds(g(U, U)) = 2 g(U, A) = 0, but this equation does not help determining the sign of g(A, A)

Comment: @AnsonīBōdo Can you see that the set of 4-vectors that are orthogonal to the unit timelike vector $\hat U$? Consider the event on the unit hyperbola at the tip of U. Can you see that the tangent hyperplane is "purely spatial" according to U? Can you see that $\hat U + \hat A$ is lightlike?